# Como obtenho resposta json no php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Tenho o link:

```
https://dominio.com/apiJSON.php?data={"login":"email@email.com","senha":"Minhasenha","campanha":"ID 1234","mensagens":{"1":{"numero":2799999999,"msg":"Uma mensagem qualquer","data":"2015-10-19 01:07:52"}}}
```

Colando esse link no navegador com os parametros corretos obtenho a seguinte resposta no navegador:

```
{"tip":1,"msg":[{"numero":2799999999,"id":"1234","status":1}]}
```

Quero pegar essa resposta e trabalhar ela com php ou com javascrpit, tanto faz. Mas preciso pegar essas informações.
Alguem pode me ajudar?
Obrigado!!!

Comment: Você pode usar um get, pra pegar o data, depois você pode usar um $var = json_decode($_GET[data]) e da um print_r($var) pra ver rsrs

Comment: Opa, vou tentar aqui amigo e respondo

Comment: @Thiago se você já resolveu o problema com alguma das respostas abaixo, você pode demonstrar isso marcando a resposta como aceita, clicando no `V` do lado esquerdo. Caso tenha encontrado outra solução diferente, você pode postar a solução como resposta, e marcar como aceite também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viva,

```
$data = file_get_contents('www.meusite.com');
$data = json_decode($data,true);
```

A partir dai é como se tivesses um array normal..

Provavelmente no teu caso teras de usar: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urlencode.php

```
file_get_contents('dominio.com/apiJSON.php?data='.urlencode(';{"login":"e‌​mail@email.com","senha":"Minhasenha","campanha":"ID 1234","mensagens":{"1":{"numero":2799999999,"msg":"Uma mensagem qualquer","data":"2015-10-19 01:07:52"}}}'))
```

Porque tens caracteres especiais..
(podes sempre enviar esses dados por post em vez de query string)

Qualquer duvida avisa ;)

Comment: Opa amigo, vou tentar aqui e aviso. Vlw

Comment: Esta me retornando o seguinte erro: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Comment: Tentou por: file_get_contents('www.dominio.com/apiJSON.php?data='.urlencode('{"login":"email@email.com","senha":"Minhasenha","campanha":"ID 1234","mensagens":{"1":{"numero":2799999999,"msg":"Uma mensagem qualquer","data":"2015-10-19 01:07:52"}}}'))

Comment: Vou tentar aqui aqui amigos, ja respondo!

Comment: Amigos, funcionou. Ele esta me retornando um array. Alguem sabe como pego cada elemento do array? Obrigado!!!

Comment: usa um foreach() para pegar os dados da array... foreach($dados as $valor){ echo $valor->nome_do_retorno; }

Comment: Opa consegui amigos, obrigado a todos. Coloco resolvido?

Comment: Ainda bem que conseguiste ;)

Answer (score 0):

$data = file_get_contents('www.meusite.com');
$data = json_decode($data);

Tenta assim :P